# Group List to List DTO using Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to group a list of `InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador` in a DTO by equal `AvaliadorEvento` using JAVA 8. Could someone help?

Bank query returns 4 lines, where ID 10 and ID 13 have the same `AvaliadorEventoId`, I would like to group them in the DTO:
[image]

`InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "inscricao_tipo_trab_aval")
@Getter
@Setter
public class InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador implements Entidade{
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="inscricao_tipo_trabalho_id")
  private InscricaoTipoTrabalho inscricaoTipoTrabalho;
    
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "avaliador_evento_id")
  private AvaliadorEvento avaliadorEvento;
    
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "situacao_avaliador")
  private SituacaoTrabalho situacaoTrabalho;

  @Transient
  private List<InscricaoTipoTrabalho> inscricaoTipoTrabalhos = new ArrayList<InscricaoTipoTrabalho>();
    
  public InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador() {
    super();    
  }
}
```

`InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorDTO`

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorDTO {

  private AvaliadorEvento avaliadorEvento;
  
  private List<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador> trabalhos;
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `List<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador> jobs`, the following should work:

```java
Map<AvaliadorEvento, List<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador>> grouped =
  jobs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador::getAvaliadorEvento));
```

Using this map you can easily create your `InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorDTO` assuming you have a constructor taking both `AvaliadorEvento` and `List<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliador>`:

```java
List<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorDTO> dtos = grouped.entrySet().stream()
  .map(entry -> new InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorDTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: very nice! thanks bro